# List not binding to filtered collection

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is my list...

```
List {
    
    ForEach(viewModel.flight.flightEvents, id: \.id) { flightEvent in
        
        ...
    }
}
```

The view model has this...

```
@Published var flight: Flight
```

`Flight` looks like this...

```
struct Flight: Identifiable {
        
    let flightEvents: [FlightEvent]
    
    let id = UUID()
}
```

`FlightEvent`...

```
struct FlightEvent: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    
    let dateComponents: DateComponents
}
```

This code results in the items in the `flightEvents` array immediately binding to the list.

If, however, I change the collection bound to the List to this...

```
viewModel.flight.flightEvents.filter { $0.dateComponents.date! <= Date() }
```

... then the items never appear in the list - the filter is false for every item to begin with. I have a workaround where I copy the filtered flight events to a different array when the user refreshes and bind this array instead.

Is there a way to have SwiftUI continuously evaluate the filter expression? I think it's not binding because the base collection hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to have SwiftUI continuously evaluate the filter expression?

Actually, no. That would cause unstoppable view redrawing, which is very undesirable. But you can set up timer (say for 1 sec, or better more) and in callback force

```
viewModel.objectWillCange.send()
```